# Scala: how to avoid var and return in map with special case

Tags: scala

Suppose that I want to write a function `foo`, which iterates over a list `List[A]` and on each element invokes some function `f`. This function returns `Option[B]`. If it encounters `None`, I want the whole function `foo` to return `None`. If it does not, I want it to return the whole list of results `List[B]`.

I could write something like this:

```
def foo(list: List[A], f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
    var res: List[B] = Nil
    for (element <- list) {
        f(element) match {
            case Some(fRes) => res = fRes :: res
            case _ => return None
        }
    }
    Some(res.reverse)
}
```

But this code seems quite ugly as I have to use `var` and `return`. Is there any way to make it look better?

**EDIT**

In this question I assume that `f` is quite time consuming function and I want to avoid calling it if we already know that the result should be `None`

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a few different ways to do this; here's about as simple as I could think of:

```
def foo(list: List[A], f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
  val x = list.map(f)
  if (x.contains(None)) {
    None
  } else {
    Some(x.flatten)
  }
}
```

You do lose the benefit of short-circuiting if you encounter a `None`. You could work around that by converting to a `Stream` and back, i.e. `val x = list.toStream.map(f)` and `Some(x.flatten.toList)`

Comment: Yes, for me the problem with `map` was that sometimes `f` is quite time consuming function. I didn't think about streams though, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def foo[A, B](list: List[A], f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
  val lst = list.view.map(f)
  if(lst.exists(_.isEmpty)) None 
  else Option { lst.flatten.to[List] }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about views in Scala, but looks like a bit more neat version of Joe K's answer

Answer (score 0):

I would write as below -

```
def foo(list: List[A], f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
    val newList = list.map(x => f(x))
    if(newList.contains(None)) None else Some(newList.flatten)
 }
```

if B is simple type like Int, Double etc but not a collection like List then the below would be very simple -

```
def foo(list: List[A], f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
   val newList = list.flatMap(f)
   if(newList.size < list.size) None else Some(newList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to using `Stream` (which I think is a cool idea) is to use an explicit tail recursion that allows shirt-circuit:

```
def foo[A, B](list: List[A])(f: (A) => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = {
  @tailrec
  def impl(list: List[A], acc: List[B]): Option[List[B]] = list match {
    case a :: rest => f(a) match {
      case Some(b) => impl(rest, b :: acc)
      case None => None
    }
    case _ => Some(acc.reverse)
  }

  impl(list, List.empty)
}
```

This is obviously more code than `Stream`-based approach but I expect that on some data it might be faster but probably not as fast (in the all-`Some` good case) as the code with simple `map` because of `acc.reverse` enforced by `List`.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is usually done recursively:

```
@tailrec
def foo(
  list: List[A], 
  result: List[B] = Nil
)(f: A => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = list match {
 case Nil => Some(result.reverse)
 case head :: tail => f(head) match {
    case Some(b) => foo(tail, b::result)(f)
    case None => None
  }
}
```

You can also write the last `case` as

```
case head::tail => f(head).flatMap { foo(tail, _ :: result)(f) }
```

but I think, that would kill the tail recursion ...